# Finding the curvature and normal vector for an arclength curve

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to find the curvature and normal vector for $$\alpha(t) = \left(\frac13 (1+t)^{3/2}, \frac13 (1-t)^{3/2}, \frac{t}{\sqrt2}\right)$$

$$\alpha'(t) = \left(\frac12 (1+t)^\frac12 , - \frac 12 (1-t)^\frac12, \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)$$
$$\|\alpha'(t)\|=\sqrt{\frac14 (1+t) + \frac 14(1-t) + \frac12}=1$$

This is an Arclength parameterization, so we don't need chain rule for the frenet equations:

Curvature is given by $\|\alpha''(t)\|$

$$\alpha''(t) = \left(\frac14 (1+t)^{-\frac12} , \frac 14 (1-t)^{-\frac12}, 0\right)$$
$$=\frac14 \left((1+t)^{-\frac12} , (1-t)^{-\frac12}, 0\right)$$
$$k(t)= \|\alpha''(t)\|=\frac14 \sqrt{(1+t)^{-1} + (1-t)^{-1}}$$
The normal vector $n(t)=\frac{\alpha''(t)}{k(t)}= \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\frac{2}{t-1}}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{t+1}}},0\right)$ isn't orthogonal to $\alpha'(t)$ though? What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe 
\begin{align*}
\alpha'(t)\cdot\alpha''(t)&=\frac{1}{8}(1+t)^{1/2}(1+t)^{-1/2}-\frac{1}{8}(1-t)^{1/2}(1-t)^{-1/2}+0\\
&=\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{8}+0\\
&=0
\end{align*}
Hence $\alpha'(t)$ and $\alpha''(t)$ are orthogonal for $-1<t<1$. Now, since $n(t)$ is parallel to $\alpha''(t)$, it follows that $\alpha'(t)$ and $n(t)$ are orthogonal too.

---

Also notice that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\alpha''(t)}{k(t)}&=\frac{\frac14 \left((1+t)^{-\frac12} , (1-t)^{-\frac12}, 0\right)}{\frac14 \sqrt{(1+t)^{-1} + (1-t)^{-1}}}\\
&=\frac{\left((1+t)^{-\frac12} , (1-t)^{-\frac12}, 0\right)}{ \sqrt{\frac{(1-t)+(1+t)}{(1+t)(1-t)}}}\\
&=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}},0\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{(1+t)(1-t)}}}\\
&=\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-t}{2}},\sqrt{\frac{1+t}{2}},0\right)
\end{align*}
Then, $$n(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left((1-t)^{1/2},(1+t)^{1/2},0\right)$$
It's not hard to show that $\alpha'(t)\cdot n(t)=0$.

Comment: That all makes sense, but does this mean you can see that my $n(t)$ was calculated right? The theory makes sense, it was just in practice that it seemed to fall apart. I took the dot product on my $n(t)$ and $\alpha'(t)$ and I just can't see how it is $0$